# cut unnecessary decimal digits in php

Tags: php, string, floating-point, number-formatting

How can I cut unnecessary zeros at the end of a floating point value in PHP, like the following for example:

```
3.0 --> 3
12.56300 --> 12.563
etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use (double) or (float) without (string)

```
echo (float)$input;
```

Comment: Great, that's even better.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way I found to do so is the following:

```
$output = (double) (string) $input;
```

Comment: It's strange that I can't accept my own answer before two days after asking my question.

Comment: This question has been asked 2 minutes ago , not 2 days ago :]

Comment: Oh , I've misunderstood you. Yes , it's a limitation of OS in order to prevent some "unwanted results" by new members.

Answer (score 0):

```
number_format($number, number of digits);
```

for example

```
echo number_format(2.222222, 2); //2.22
```

Comment: This is not answering the question as I wasn't asking for a fixed number of digits.